# Shape isomorphism code fails on specific values

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, graph-algorithm

I have written a code that checks whether 2 trees are isomorphic or not:

```
n = int(input())
parent1 = [int(item) for item in input().split()]
parent2 = [int(item) for item in input().split()]


#Structure to store information about nodes
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def add_child(self, node):
        if not self.left:
            self.left = node
        elif not self.right:
            self.right = node

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'TreeNode({self.data!r}, {self.left!r}, {self.right!r})'.format(self=self)



 # Function which converts trees from parent array representation into the usual one.
def construct_tree(parents: list):

    # Put Nodes with corresponding values into the list
    constructed = [TreeNode(i) for i in range(len(parents))]

    root = None
    for i, parent in enumerate(parents):

        # If parent's index = -1, it's the root of the tree
        if parent == -1:
            root = constructed[i]
        else:
            # Tie up current node to corresponding parent
            constructed[parent].add_child(constructed[i])

    return root

def are_isomorphic(T1, T2):
    # Both roots are empty, trees are isomorphic by default

    if len(parent1) != len(parent2):
        return False

    if T1 is None and T2 is None:
        return True
    #if T1.data != T2.data Gives the wrong answer

    # If one of the trees is empty, and the other - isn't, do not bother to check further.
    if T1 is None or T2 is None:
        return False

    # There are two possible cases for n1 and n2 to be isomorphic
    # 1: The subtrees rooted at these nodes haven't been swapped
    # 2: The subtrees rooted at these nodes have been swapped
    return (are_isomorphic(T1.left, T2.left) and are_isomorphic(T1.right, T2.right) or
            are_isomorphic(T1.left, T2.right) and are_isomorphic(T1.right, T2.left))
```

It gives the right answer practically for every tree pair , except these:

> TreeNode(0, TreeNode(1, TreeNode(3, None, None), TreeNode(4, None,
>   None)), TreeNode(2, None, None))
>
> TreeNode(0, TreeNode(1, TreeNode(3, None, None), None), TreeNode(2,
>   TreeNode(4, None, None), None))

They aren't isomorphic, but my code determines that they are.

I drew these trees and thought this situation is included into the recursive procedure.
I tried this:

```
if are_isomorphic(T1.left, T2.left) is False:
    return "No"

if are_isomorphic(T1.left, T2.right) is False:
    return "No"

if are_isomorphic(T1.right, T2.left) is False:
    return "No"

if are_isomorphic(T1.right, T2.right) is False:
    return "No"

else:
    return "Yes"
```

and this:

```
    if (are_isomorphic(T1.left, T2.left) and are_isomorphic(T1.right, T2.right) is False):
        return "No"

    elif (are_isomorphic(T1.left, T2.right and are_isomorphic(T1.right, T2.left) ) is False):
        return "No"

    else:
        return "Yes"
```

Can someone please explain what am I missing?

Comment: This function doesn't define `parent1` or `parent2`. Also, how is your `__len__` function implemented? It may be contributing to the problem.

Comment: `parent1` and `parent2` are the parent arrays of the treesm, they are input from console. I didn't include the code building trees from parent array cause it works properly and irrelevant to the question.
len() is a built-in python function.

Comment: Yes, but what is it measuring? `[3, None, None]` has the same length as `[1, 2, None]`.

Comment: You don't seem to check all the options where two trees `are` isomorphic.

Comment: @aryamccarthy, nono, look. It asks, whether the first tree can be swapped (transformed) into the other tree. Look at these trees: they have the same number of vertices, but non-isomorphic. https://ibb.co/eMxCJ5
https://ibb.co/bOimd5

Comment: @boardrider, yes, this is exactly what I thought may the problem be, but then I stuck trying to implement it.

Comment: Please post the definition of TreeNode

Comment: Edit your question to display the _missing conditions_ and your attempt at their implementation, and the good souls of SO may offer help...

Comment: @saulspatz, done.

Comment: @TheDoctor I just ran your original code on your example (after commenting out the line comparing the parents) and it returned `False`.  Please verify that the example you have posted is the same as the example you ran.

Comment: @saulspatz, that's strange. How did you set  `parent1 ` and  `parent2 `?
Here's what I tested: 
 `5 /br
-1 0 0 1 1 /br
-1 0 0 1 2 `
That gives exactly that couple of TreeNode(...) sequences I put above.

Comment: @TheDoctor I didn't set `parent1` or `parent2` and I removed the line that compared their lengths.  Your isomorphism code is correct, as far as I can see.  I'll post the code I ran as an answer, so you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but there's no way to post the code in a comment.  As I said, it looks to me like your code produces the correct result on the example you gave.

```
#Structure to store information about nodes
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def add_child(self, node):
        if not self.left:
            self.left = node
        elif not self.right:
            self.right = node

def are_isomorphic(T1, T2):
    # Both roots are empty, trees are isomorphic by default

    #if len(parent1) != len(parent2):
        #return False

    if T1 is None and T2 is None:
        return True
    #if T1.data != T2.data Gives the wrong answer

    # If one of the trees is empty, and the other - isn't, do not bother to check further.
    if T1 is None or T2 is None:
        return False

    # There are two possible cases for n1 and n2 to be isomorphic
    # 1: The subtrees rooted at these nodes haven't been swapped
    # 2: The subtrees rooted at these nodes have been swapped
    return (are_isomorphic(T1.left, T2.left) and are_isomorphic(T1.right, T2.right) or
            are_isomorphic(T1.left, T2.right) and are_isomorphic(T1.right, T2.left))

T1=TreeNode(0, TreeNode(1, TreeNode(3, None, None), TreeNode(4, None, None)), TreeNode(2, None, None))

T2=TreeNode(0, TreeNode(1, TreeNode(3, None, None), None), TreeNode(2, TreeNode(4, None, None), None))

print(are_isomorphic(T1, T2))
```

The above prints `False`.  If there's a problem, it must be in the way you're constructing the tree.

Comment: very strange.
Thank you, It seems, not only the correctness of the output tree, but also how it builds has an influence.

Comment: I copied my own code into the other IDE and everything worked.
I am still surprised.